# ruby high use of memory, possibly leakage

Tags: ruby, memory

I am using Ruby 1.9.3p0. The program that I wrote uses a lot of Memory when I run it for more than 4 hours. I am using the following gems:

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'cgi'
require 'domainatrix'
```

This following code is run for more than 10.000 times, and I suspect it may cause a leak.

```
  File.open('output.txt', 'a') do |file|
            output.each_line do |item|
                    item = item.match(/^[^\s]+/)
                    item = item.to_s
                    if item = item.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+\..+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/)
                    item = item.to_s
                            if item.length > 1
                                    #puts "item: #{item}"
                                    #item = item.to_s
                                    item = Domainatrix.parse(item)
                                    puts "subdomain: #{item.subdomain}"
                                    if (item.domain == domain)
                                            file.puts item.subdomain
                                            puts item.subdomain
                                    end
                            end
                    end
            end
    end
```

On the other hand, I am using a hash table to store every link.

What do you think may cause the Ruby to use a lot of memory?

**UPDATE**

Also I believe File.open should be closed after it is used. Is it true?

Comment: **Ruby 1.9.3p0 is out-of-date and has known security vulnerabilities**. You should upgrade to the latest 1.9.3 (currently 1.9.3-p448) or 2.0.0 ASAP.

Comment: Also `File.open` with a block automatically closes the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> first don't require 'rubygems' not required in ruby 1.9.
>
>
>
> you forgot to use ')' after if condition.
> ```

```
   if (item.domain == domain
```

> ```
> yes File.open closes the file.
> ```

Comment: So what's your solution to this memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

It shall cause a syntax error before running.

Comment: You are probably calling this from another file with a `rescue`.

Comment: Yep you are right, I am using begin and rescue to catch exceptions, but what's your solution?